# Unable to load class 'kotlin.reflect.KDeclarationContainer'.android studio 3.1.4

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-reflect, android-studio-3.1.4

i am new in kotlin and when install kotlin in android step by step 
in building project i got this error 
search a lot about how fix this problem but didn't work any solution like invalidate cache/reset 
please help me

Comment: is your internet well?maybe its unable to load that class

Comment: i am sure my internet is well, @ALTegani

Comment: what about rebuild the project

Comment: i did it ,dosent solve my problem but i found this error in error log  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/KDeclarationContainer"  so i check my library find KDeclarationContainerImpl and KdeclarationContainer (interface) but didnt find clas KDeclarationContainer 
so what can i do??? @ALTegani

Comment: Got same problem, just recently everything worked well, but  stopped working. Now I have `kotlin-reflect` in my classpath, it's declared in MANIFEST.MF and present in jar locally, tried `kotlin-reflect` versions `1.2.21`, `1.2.51`, `1.2.60`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `kotlin-reflect` to you `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: '1.2.61'
```